# Execute a list of Threads in parallel

Tags: java, thread-safety

I have a list of Script that i want to execute them in parallel, i already find this way in [Creating dynamic number of threads concurrently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10092317/5558072), so i use this piece of code here :

```
private int i;//<---------------------------------(1)
private String[] listScript = {"Script1", "Script2", "Script3", "Script4"};

private void executeQueries() throws InterruptedException {

    ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(listScript.length);
    // submit jobs to be executing by the pool
    for (i = 0; i < listScript.length; i++) {
        threadPool.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                executeQuerie();
            }
        });
        Thread.sleep(500);//<---------------------(2)
    }
    // once you've submitted your last job to the service it should be shut down
    threadPool.shutdown();
    // wait for the threads to finish if necessary
    threadPool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

}

private void executeQuerie() {
    //execute scripts action
    System.out.println(listScript[i]);
}
```

I'm really not happy with this code, i will explain a little my code so you can understand more :

(1). I use this `i` variable outside the method so i can know which script i should to execute
  (2). I use `Thread.sleep(500);` to make sure that i execute the right script, without this i can execute the same script multiple time for example it can gives me:

```
Script1
Script1
Script2
Script2
```

My question is : how can i make sure that my scripts executed safely in parallel, should i improve this piece of code, or do you have any other safe way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make `i` a parameter of executeQuery :

```
private String[] listScript = {"Script1", "Script2", "Script3", "Script4"};

private void executeQueries() throws InterruptedException {

    ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(listScript.length);
    // submit jobs to be executing by the pool
    for (int i = 0; i < listScript.length; i++) {
        final int j = i;
        threadPool.submit(() -> executeQuery(j));
    }
    // once you've submitted your last job to the service it should be shut down
    threadPool.shutdown();
    // wait for the threads to finish if necessary
    threadPool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

}

private void executeQuery(final int index) {
    System.out.println(listScript[index]);
}
```

I used lambda here as it's simply less verbose. `j` is needed as `i` must be `final` for the closure to work ;)

Also `awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE...` isn't a very good idea.... It's over 10 millions years you know ? ^^

Comment: but you can't use the `i` like you do `threadPool.submit(() -> executeQuery(i));`

Comment: @YCF_L yup I used another variable, I just edited my post with an added comment about this

Comment: it still the same problem :(

Comment: @YCF_L ??? it's working properly with `j` on my computer

Comment: sorry my bad, i was using java 7

Comment: it work but the the scripts are not ordered why?

Comment: @YCF_L isn't that the point of parrallel execution ? ^^ you can use Thread.sleep if you want them to be ordered but that's not very good looking... if you want a more definitive answer, then this is a question you should check over StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need to have control over the amount of threads used to perform the work, you could consider parallel streams and you are done with these simple lines:

```
private String[] listScript = {"Script1", "Script2", "Script3", "Script4"};

private void executeQueries() {

    Arrays.asList(listScript).parallelStream().forEach(script -> {

        System.out.println(script + " runs in thread " + Thread.currentThread());

        try { Thread.sleep(5000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {}

    });

}
```